# When do credit downgrades usually take place?

Tags: credit

Do credit downgrades most often occur during earnings season? or are they uniform over the year?

Answer (score 2):

Up and downgrades are based on fundamental analysis, technical analysis, and current news. Analysts regularly reevaluate the stocks that they follow so they periodically reiterate expectations or change them.

Quarterly earnings announcements result in a larger number of concentrated releases with the exception of a volatile market correction such as we are experiencing now which results in a plethora of downgrades.

Comment: This answer seems geared to stock ratings whereas the question was about credit (bond) ratings. I would be surprised if bond ratings (Moody's, S&P, Fitch) make any significant use of technical analysis. Moreover, moves in the stock market would not *directly* affect bond ratings unless there are corresponding fundamental changes in companies' solvency.

Comment: @nanoman - The OP mentioned earnings season so I went on that. However, if you feel that earnings announcements are relevant to bond ratings, I won't argue the point.

Comment: @BobBaerker this is w.r.t creditratings